# is there a way to delete the first help message discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so I have this code

```
@bot.group()
async def help(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f'Help', description = 'user -help <command> to get more info on that command',color=0xFF0000)
    em.add_field(name = 'Moderation', value = 'psa, purge')
    em.add_field(name = 'Fun', value = 'hi, numbers')
    em.add_field(name = 'help', value = 'mod, support')
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@help.command()
async def psa(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f'psa', description = 'Takes the channel name and your message and makes it embed',color=0xFF0000)
    em.add_field(name = '**Syntax**', value = '-psa [message]')
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

and when I do -help psa it shows the first help screen. Is there a way to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.group()
@help.command()
```

you should change it to

```
@bot.group(name='help')
@help.command(name='psa')
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `invoke_without_command` to the group, see the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command)

```py
@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def help(ctx):
```